# Karma Unit Test Error [Phantom Browser]

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, jhipster

I create my project using jhipster and I combine it with a theme that I bought from themeforest.
But when I try to create a war, I got error like this. It is like theme's component get error when tested with karma

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) ERROR
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$.fn.vectorMap')
  at /Volumes/Permanent/STS-Workspace/emsv2/src/main/webapp/scripts/libs/jquery/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js:1

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) ERROR
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.fn.tooltip.Constructor')
  at /Volumes/Permanent/STS-Workspace/emsv2/src/main/webapp/scripts/libs/jquery/popover/bootstrap-popover.js:37

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) ERROR
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.fn.tooltip.Constructor')
  at /Volumes/Permanent/STS-Workspace/emsv2/src/main/webapp/scripts/libs/jquery/popover/popover.js:32
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you install your theme?

Usually, when installing a client dependency in JHipster, you use bower which takes care of updating index.html and karma.conf.js. If you installed manually by yourself you have to do it in both files.